# Unity Event.current is null reference, only s_Current available

Tags: events, unity-game-engine

```
Event e = Event.current;
```

This compiles.  But it gives a null reference execption on runtime.

Using the debugger I find

```
Event e = Event.s_Current; // is ok
Event e = Event.s_MasterEvent; // both these exist
```

Those objects exist and have what I want, but this doesnt compile.

I am using unity 5.0.1f1 Personal.  Heeelp please!

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Event.html

Event.current will always be null outside of OnGUI(), this is what's causing your exception.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/661247/using-eventsnullreferenceexception.html